# Jquery tablesorter pagination is not separating pages correctly on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, tablesorter

So I am using the pagination plugin with tablesorter (tablesorter.com)  and I changed the values in the pagesize drop down box but it does not correctly adjust the pages unless I click the combo box again after the page loads.  However if I leave the default values in (10,20,30)  then it is working correctly.  It will load the page and only show 10 rows and then allow me to go to next page for the rest of the rows etc.  I need to limit pages to 100 results instead of 10.  for testing sake I was trying to change it to limit to 5 rows but it is not adjusting correctly until I click 5 in the drop down after the page loads. this is my current code.

HTML

```
<div id="pager" class="pager">
<form>
    <img src="images/first.png" class="first"/>
    <img src="images/prev.png" class="prev"/>
    <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
    <img src="images/next.png" class="next"/>
    <img src="images/last.png" class="last"/>
    <select class="pagesize">
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>  
    </select>
</form>
</div>
```

javascript

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#distributorTable").tablesorter({ headers: { 1:{sorter:false} } } );
        $("#distributorTable").tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 

    } 
);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution right after posting this. You can send in a value for size when using the pagination function which will set the initial page size.

Javascript

```
$("#distributorTable").tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), size:5});
```